# Should i use notifyDataSetChanged or update ListView items individually?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've got a question about the performance of a ListView. My application uses a ListView with approximately 20 items and i was wondering what should i do if the data of one item has changed. Should i call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter and cause a redraw of the whole  list or should i take care only of the item to refresh itself?

What is the cost of `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Can i use this without hesitation? An ListView item of mine has about 3-4 TextViews and an ImageView.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When dealing with listview (or any other adapter classes) you must also think about what happens when this view is going to be re used. Handling this case is troublesome, think of different approach if performance is what you are after (like reducing the view hierarchy in list child item etc...)

Answer (score 2):

notifyDatasetChanged refreshes the whole list each time its called so it is better if you call that after you have all of your data that you want so you are not doing unnecessary work

Comment: Assuming that i need to refresh one ore two items every 2 seconds you would suggest to implement a way to redraw only these items, right?

Comment: yes I would try to think of a way to update them individually if you can but I cant see it being an easy task. if you are going to call notifyDatasetChanged every 2 seconds it is going to cause unnecessary overhead so it is not something I would recommend doing

Comment: For other people facing this issue this might be useful: http://erikw.eu/android-update-single-item-in-listview/ I've tried this but it didn't worked for me. The item will only be redrawn after scrolling out and in.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mMyListView.invalidate();
mMyListView.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Is there a noticeable difference to notifyDataSetChanged()? invalidateViews() (called on the adapter?) will redraw the whole list as well, wont it?